# Balancing a game with unevenly matched teams?

Tags: algorithm, prediction, game-theory

I've implemented a multi-day online event for my game where 3-4 teams of an arbitrary number of players compete by playing games on their individual devices.

Each game they play is worth some number of points which are added to their team score when the game is completed.

The teams are unbalanced, which isn't very much fun for the losing teams, so I would like to boost the scores of the losing teams with some sort of handicap that would balance the competition and give every team a reasonable and fair chance to win.

My thought is to use the individual scores over the course of the event to continually refine a prediction of the final score for each team at the conclusion of the event, and use that prediction to weight the future individual scores for the teams such that the predicted outcome would be a tie.

The problem I'm having with this idea is coming up with a good prediction algorithm. If I use a simple average of past performance to predict future performance, the algorithm favors a team that waits to play until the end of the event, which is undesirable. If I use a window function that only considers recent performance to predict the outcome, the prediction swings wildly as the scores are submitted in bursts with long delays between them, for example, as team members sleep.

Is this a good path to pursue? Can anyone recommend a better prediction algorithm? Or perhaps an entirely different way to balance the teams?

Comment: The problem with any handicapping system is that it creates an incentive to play badly (to boost the handicap). And then play well in games that matter (using the unfair handicap to guarantee victory). The only way to counter that is to base the player's handicap on a long history of games that matter. Which is to say that I think the player handicaps should be fixed in stone at the beginning of the event, and should not change during the event. Over the course of several multi-day events, you can refine the player handicaps based on past performance.

Comment: Agreed in general. However, in this case, the teams consist of thousands of players, many of whom are inactive or only active in bursts over the course of the event. So I think the performance of individual players isn’t a good indicator of the overall team performance. It’s also much more difficult to coordinate all of the team players to game the handicapping algorithm as there are other incentives to play as an individual (which still counts for the team). I’m thinking a good handicapping algorithm will evaluate the overall team performance as a single entity rather than individual members.

Comment: Intuitively I feel that past performance of a team doesn’t necessarily correlate with future performance given the dynamic nature of the team play. The team events happen on a schedule but players may or may not play during a given event time window. Also, new players are joining and choosing teams all the time. Which is to say that a fixed handicap based on pervious events may be wildly inaccurate.

Comment: Here's a thought. Track the tournament average score. For each team, discard the scores that are farthest from the average, and sum the remaining scores for the team score. For example, let's say that each team has 5 players, the tournament average score is 100, and we discard two scores. The individual score for Team SuperStar are {130,120,110,100,90}. Farthest from the average are 130 and 120, so those are discarded. Team score: 300. Team Newbie scores are {110,100,90,80,70}. Throw out 80 and 70. Team score: 300. Team Mediocre scores are {120,110,100,90,80}. Toss 120 and 80. Team score: 300.

Comment: Interesting idea! I think any kind of score prediction based on an average over the entire event doesn’t respond quickly enough to a burst of activity, for example, toward the end of the event, which would give an advantage to a team who didn’t play much until the end of the event, which is undesirable.